# Reducing a set of generators to a free base

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

Given an algebraic structure $ A $ which is free on some subset of its underlying set, does every generating subset of $ A $ contain a free generating set?

For vector spaces, this is true, what about the general case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free abelian group $\;\Bbb Z\;$ is generated by $\;\{2,3\}\;$ . Can you find a **free generating** subset in this case?